# How to disable text style copying on Windows XP?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, copy-paste, clipboard

Problem: I copy a text from a website, paste it on email or forum, and scream for the insanely large font it creates. Then I instantly go to notepad and re-paste, re-copy and again re-paste it to get rid of the styling.

Is there a solution for this annoyance and pasteing delay, which doesn't require me to use different buttons for paste? Note: this should work on any program, not just on a browser.

I have no idea why would I ever want to use this feature, unless I copy text between word documents, which I do extremely rarely.

Perhaps the best solution would be a program that removes the styling after new textual data was added to clipboard.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't used XP lately, but, in the receiving program, there is usually an option under Edit or Insert called Paste Special or Paste Without Formatting that gives you the option of pasting without formatting. That will do it.

To find it, you usually have to select Edit or Insert from the menu bar of the receiving program. It usually doesn't show up in context dependent menus (when you right click in a document, etc. and a menu of options appears).

If not, you can do it the hard way by opening a text editor like notepad (not a word processor) window and pasting the selection there. That will strip most or all of the formatting. If any is left, you will see it as plain text and can just delete it manually.

Once you have the plain text in the editor (notepad), you can then copy and paste it to its final destination.

Just reread your question and saw that you already use the"hard way". I'll leave it in my answer for others to see.

Comment: Some programs have that option, yes. Not everyone. Especially on websites. On top of all this, that would require me to stop using CTRL+V and use tedious mouse clicks. And only if it was supported on all possible programs on this universe.

Comment: Yes, not all programs support that, but on the ones that do, it really helps. If you don't mind doing some extra work, you might be able to automate some or all of the "hard way" by writing macros in AutoKey and assigning them to shortcut key(s). This would not be a beginner level macro, but, if you know a little Python (the macro language AutoKey uses), it's not rocket science either. In general, it's worth exploring because, with AutoKey, you can add all sorts of custom features to your gui without programming them from scratch. Oops, had my Linux hat on. Try AutoHotKey. That's for Windows.

Comment: I think i better off figuring out how to modify the clipboard data with some real programming languages, and simply filter them out from all textual data. unless someone has already made such a program?

Comment: If you want your solution to be seamless, like it's a part of Windows, then programming is definitely the way to go. You can still use things like AutoHotKey for rapid prototyping so you already have a solution that works when you start coding.

Comment: As to the default behaviour: On Linux, I regularly run into situations where I try to print a selection of a web page and it either formats things very badly or the print comes out too small to read. Then, I open LibreOffice Writer and paste into that and it fixes most of the problems automatically. I print it and then discard the document. Works great. A few websites are coded so weird that I have to paste into a text editor to get rid of all the formatting to get something useful. Kim Komando's website is one of those. Lots of good (end user) Windows info, but you have to work to extract it.